# Istio Proxy blocking TCP Traffic

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, istio, istio-sidecar

Currently, we have a deployment file with an init container which test connectivity to the DB as per below:

```
- name: wait-database
      image: 'busybox:4.3.13'
      command:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          until nc -w3 -z testdb.local 1521; do echo waiting for
          oracle; sleep 3; done;
      resources: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

A service entry has been created as per below:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-oracle-db
spec:
  hosts:
    - testdb.local
  addresses:
    - 10.120.1.76/16
  ports:
    - name: tcp
      number: 1521
      protocol: tcp
```

Without the proxy running as a sidecar, the command executes successfully on init container but with the proxy running, it does not get executed. Is there any particular policy I need to run on the node.
Thanks.

Comment: If possible can you add  the error you are getting in logs while trying to execute the command  on init container.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. It just keep outputting waiting for oracle.